# mouse over text for textfield in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have created a textField like this.

```
comp = new Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel : 'Name', 
            value : defVal,
            width : width,
            labelStyle : lblStyle,
            blankText : 'field required',
            invalidText : 'invalid text'
        });
```

I want to have a mouse-over text for this field which displays 'enter your name' when mouse tip is moved over the field. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ext JS 3 and want to add a tooltip over the input area of your field (not over the label), try the following:

```
comp = new Ext.form.TextField({...});

var tooltipText = 'Enter your name';

Ext.QuickTips.init();

Ext.QuickTips.register({
    target: comp,
    title: '',
    width: 250,
    text: tooltipText
});
```